# Include a semicolon as part of a string to search in Python

Tags: python, regex

So I am slightly new to Python but familiar with other scripting languages. How do you include a semicolon in a search string with Python correctly. Whenever I do, I assume python is interpreting it as a new code block and their for not returning the proper results. See sample below:

Sample text file:

```
<value> I; want; this; line; </value>
<value> And; this; line; </value>
<value> I dont want this line </value>
```

Code:

```
import os
import re

find = "<value>*;*"
filename = "C:\\temp\\Sample.txt"

with open (filename, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if re.match(find, line):
            print(line)
```

It is returning all lines rather than just the first and second lines. I have tried multiple different methods around this (including this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356307/parsing-searching-a-comma-and-semicolon-separated-string-in-python)) but nothing seams to work. There has to be a simple way to do this, or is Python just really this annoying to work with?

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple I was missing but yes I got it confused with other languages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're confusing regex with another wildcard language (e.g. [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax)). `*` means zero or more of the *preceding* expression, not zero or more of anything. You need to use `.` to represent anything.

```
find = "<value>.*;.*"
```

To be clear, the problem doesn't really have anything to do with Python.

Check out the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) for more details about using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wildcard pattern rather than a regexp. The regexp `<value>*;*` matches `<value` followed by zero or more `>` followed by zero or more `;`. Every line matches because they all begin with `<value`.

The correct regexp is

```
find = "<value>.*;"
```

`.` matches any character, and `*` means to match any number of them. Then it matches `;`.

I suggest you read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.